# reading line numbers and character positions of elements in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I've got an XML document I'm reading to provide some settings, like so;

```
01 <Layout>
02   <Variable name="leftEdge" value="100" />
03   <Rectangle x="leftEdge" y="100" />        
04   <Rectangle x="leftEdge2" y="100" />        
05 </Layout>
```

I'm loading this document and querying it for elements, but I have some fairly complex validation rules that can't be covered by XSD. What I'd like to do is provide some rich errors on problems in the document, like so;

```
ERROR: Rectangle at line 04 char 03: no variable called 'LeftEdge2' has been defined.
```

But at the moment I'm loading into `XmlDocument` which doesn't remember where elements were defined in the original file.

Does anyne know of a component or method where I can tag an XmlElement with its original line and character position? So that I could write;

```
var errorMessage = string.Format(
    "ERROR: {0} at line {1} char {2}: no variable called '{3}' has been defined.", 
    element.Name, 
    element.OriginalLineNumber, 
    element.OriginalCharacterNumber,
    missingVariableName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd a similar requirement a few years ago. We ended using MSXML component, imported as COM+.